# Google Image Search how to get number of similar images

Tags: javascript, json, image, google-image-search

I am new to JavaScript. I have a website on which people post their pictures.  When people post their images, I would like to put the number of similar pictures that Google Image Search found. Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Very rarely do people just simply write code for you. We'd like to see you put some effort into your code and display it in the question. Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want to see how.

Comment: A resource I'd recommend you check out for this particular question would be this: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: Will note that, thanks!